# Audio Players is not working, AVPlayerItem.Status.failed iOS

Tags: flutter, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to use the plugin Audio Players for my recorded audios ( it's working perfectly for android ) but when I try to play the audio I get this error:

```
"iOS => call setVolume, playerId 57c0b5cc-3c75-4f8f-bf99-ad8ddbcb7709"
"iOS => call setUrl, playerId 57c0b5cc-3c75-4f8f-bf99-ad8ddbcb7709"
""
2022-06-23 18:27:00.168194-0300 Runner[16264:695114] flutter: AVPlayerItem.Status.failed
```

Any idea of what can I do to solve this problem?

```
await audioPlayer2.setVolume(1.0);
      await audioPlayer2.setUrl(filepath, isLocal: true);
      await audioPlayer2.play(filepath, isLocal: true);
      audioPlayer2.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((event) {
        setState(() {
          _isPlaying = false;
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `setUrl` and then play I only used this:

```
final _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.stop);
await _audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(widget.postData.audioURL));
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to add capabilities in xcode

Go to xcode -> runner -> add capabilities

Inter-App Audio

Thanks